# startActivityForResult calling window killed before result returned

Tags: android

I have a launcher app that is attempting to add widgets. Most work fine, but if you have a configure screen, the widget is never added. The launcher calls

```
REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET = 9
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET);
```

and the configure activity is launched, but as its coming up i see this in the lolcat

```
W/WindowManager( 2096): Rebuild removed 7 windows but added 6
    W/WindowManager( 2096): This window was lost: Window{42abf130 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.AppWidgetPickActivity paused=false}
```

The configure finishes and nothing happens because the appwidgetpicker is already dead.

The launcher never actually crashes, theres never anything bad that happens, just nothing happens. Its not the app itself that is crashing, its the systemappwindgetpicker afaik.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but in your pickIntent definition, should you have `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE` instead of `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/T3hh4xx0r/Hax-Launcher/commit/4b6d2d99fdef0ded0684688a2ac5ddeb2faa9f1d

Somewhere along the line, a variable was getting nullified. I just created a backup basically to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know what the problem is, but one of these threads might be of help to you:

[Drop event when select OK to restart Launcher when ANR occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365043/drop-event-when-select-ok-to-restart-launcher-when-anr-occurs)

[Android - problems with a multi-level activity chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789244/android-problems-with-a-multi-level-activity-chain)